# if js is available use ajax instead html form

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have to set up a huge amount of html forms which send data to a php backend. I would start building html forms "the old fashioned way" sending post data on submit. As a "sur plus" I would setup ajax requests with jquery on top (if user has js enabled).

my steps:

1. check if js is available, if not stay with html form submit if
2. stop form submit with prevent.default
3. send data by ajax requests

This seems a lot of extra work. Is there a trick or "best practice" to make life a bit easier?

Comment: trivial -> use <noscript>tags</noscript>

Comment: mhhh I think this would produce even more work then my way above …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the trick is simple:

```
$(function() {
  ...
  $('form').someAjaxSubmit({...my options..});
  ...
});
```

where ajaxSubmit is [one](http://plugins.jquery.com/form/) or [another](http://plugins.jquery.com/form/) version of the jQuery plugin for the purpose. Of course, you will need to think where the output will go to etc.

If you have no JS, the code above will obviously not execute and forms will be working "the old way". You can tweak the plugin to get everything from the form attributes and to not require code changes - unless your web application data flow logic prevents it for some reason. Usually problems arise because of the form submission result format and how to handle it; but even full html page can be parsed and its body set instead of the current body - but I consider it a cludge. It is much better to change only what is needed in DOM on form submission success.

If it is possible to tweak the server, nicer way of building the response is to check for `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` header and only send content block update as html fragment or even JSON.

Comment: great, this plugin was what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. check if js is available => wrap the form in  tag. it will be displayed only if the JS isn't working.
2. For stopping the form submit and send the data, if you work with Jquery it is very simple. For stopping you only add this:

   ```
   $("form").submit(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); ...
   ```

And for submitting you have a wide and simple-to-use API in jquery : load function, ajax function, etc. Look at their documentation or examples for this.

I don't think that you should work here with a plugin or a library because it is very simple. You should work with plugins and libraries only when you should write many lines of some topic (like validation), but for this - I think you should write it alone. It also will improve yourself as a programmer.

Comment: thanks RanSch for your wide answer. The steps you describe are the one I was thinking of. I see your point, this is no hard job but in this case I´m trying to get this running in no time ;) will try the mentioned plugin